# What happens when I copy two empty paths and why doesn't it throw an exception?

Tags: java, file, path, filesystems, copy

I'm really wondering what this code does:

```
scala> import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file._

scala> Files.copy(Paths.get(""), Paths.get(""))
res0: java.nio.file.Path =
```

Shouldn't that throw a `NoSuchFileException`?

Reading the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) reveals:

> By default, the copy fails if the target file already exists or is a
>   symbolic link, except if the source and target are the same file, in
>   which case the method completes without copying the file.

But I'm not sure this is the true cause, because `Files.copy(Paths.get("a"), Paths.get("a"))` fails as expected.

Comment: The question is not Scala specific. I just used it to show the code and the interaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html for what paths.get does when provided an empty string (it generates an empty path) and http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html for details on what an empty path means:

> A Path is considered to be an empty path if it consists solely of one
>   name element that is empty. Accessing a file using an empty path is
>   equivalent to accessing the default directory of the file system.

So it looks like your code is getting an empty path which is valid and then considers the source and destination to be the same.

Comment: when it copies a directory, it creates an empty directory, like the docs linked  mentions. So, actualy, it creates an empty directory in `dest`

Comment: I'm not a great java expert unfortunately. Was just going by a reading of the docs and I wouldn't have been surprised if it compares the two copy parameters to see if they are identical before it does anything with significantly more overhead like looking at the file system. I just would have thought that if it created an empty directory in `dest` that it would return the path to that and that that path would not be empty.