# Behavior of exists() method in java.nio.file.Files class

Tags: java, nio

I'm testing if a file exists using the new classes in the Java nio package, but I'm getting a result that seems a bug:

The following code:

```
Path p = Paths.get("");
System.err.println("[" + p.getFileName().toString() + "]");
System.err.println("[" + p.getParent() + "]");
System.err.println(Files.exists(p));
```

Produces the output:

```
[]
[null]
true
```

Why does it print true? Is this a bug or is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Have you checked the path's absolute location? [Path.toAbsolutePath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath\(\))

Comment: @Aaron, it prints the parent directory, but that shouldn't be enough for the method to print true, right?

Comment: Why not? The parent directory exists, doesn't it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34459486/1743880 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6831605/1743880

Comment: The documentation states: "true if the file exists; false if the file does not exists or its existence cannot be determined". Since it is pointing to a directory, I was not expecting it to be true.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Do directories not exist?

Answer (score 1):

`""` is the path where you execute your app.

Try this:

```
System.err.println(p.toFile().getAbsolutePath());
```

Then you will see where you are.

Comment: It prints a directory, not a file.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira And that directory exists. A directory and a file are both paths (and on some systems, directories **are** files)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, even on Windows?

Comment: On Windows a directory is not a file, but it is still a path, and it exists.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I'm just questioning that the method is not doing what the documentation says it does. It is supposed to check if a file exists, not a directory, not a resource. The same way it says the createFile creates a file. Or can I assume this method also creates directories?

Comment: The introduction of `Files` says _"This class consists exclusively of static methods that operate on files, directories, or other types of files."_ . I think the documentation writer didn't feel the need to continuously write "files, directories, or other types of files". So the usage of the term file includes directories (eg look at `java.io.File`), and the terminology above (_**other types of files**_). It would be very odd if `Files.exists()` wouldn't report existence of directories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105019/discussion-between-mark-rotteveel-and-carlos-ferreira).

Answer (score 0):

From the javadocs for the `Path` class:

> "A Path is considered to be an empty path if it consists solely of one name element that is empty. Accessing a file using an empty path is equivalent to accessing the default directory of the file system."

You have created an empty path, and the `exists()` call is testing if the "default directory of the file system" exists.  It does.

What you are seeing is "expected behavior".

Note that the "default directory" could mean different things depending on the host platform, but on UNIX based systems and Windows, it means the "current directory" for the JVM.